# Not understanding for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, cube

I need to find the cube root of a perfect cube using a for loop but I don't know why my code won't work:

```
n = int(input('n = '))
for guess in range(0, n+1):
    if guess**3 != n:
        guess = guess + 1
    if guess**3 == n:
        print(guess, 'is the cube root of', n)
    if guess**3 != n:
        print("not a perfect cube")
```

and if I input the number 8 (for example), it will print out:

```
n = 8
not a perfect cube
2 is the cube root of 8
2 is the cube root of 8
not a perfect cube
not a perfect cube
not a perfect cube
not a perfect cube
not a perfect cube
not a perfect cube
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me realize what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you dont need to manually change the guess in a for loop, the loop does that automatically

Comment: As @ChristianSloper mentioned, you're modifying `guess` twice. Additionally, you probably want to rewrite it as an `if / else` block instead of multiple `if` statements. Finally, right now, that last `if guess**3 != n:` is getting called every time the loop executes. It looks like you want that to be something that only happens once, after all possible guesses have been evaluated.

Comment: How does it not work? What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

n**(1/3) will also give you the cube root of n.

Your code can be improved by:

```
    n = int(input('n = '))
    for guess in range(0, n+1):
        if guess**3 == n:
            print(guess, 'is the cube root of', n)
            break
    else:
        print("not a perfect cube")
```

You don't need guess=guess+1

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to write this:

```py
n = int(input('n = '))
for guess in range(1, n + 1):
    if guess ** 3 == n:
        print(guess, 'is the cube root of', n)
        break
else:
    print("not a perfect cube")
```

As has been pointed out, the reason to have `for guess in range(...):` is so that the `for` loop increments `guess` for you.

I have moved the failure case to an `else:` clause of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using `range` in a `for` loop will increment `guess`. You can take out this:

```
    if guess**3 != n:
        guess = guess + 1
```

You don't want to check if it's not a perfect cube for each `guess`. You know it's not a perfect cube once you've gone through all the `guess`es. Therefore this logic needs to happen after the `for` loop.

```
    if guess**3 != n:
        print("not a perfect cube")
```

I store the `root` in a variable and check it.

```
n = int(input('n = '))
root = -1;
for guess in range(0, n):
    if guess**3 == n:
        root = guess

if root > -1:
    print(root, 'is the cube root of', n)
else:
    print("not a perfect cube")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code instead:

```
n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

for ans in range(0, abs(n) + 1):
    if ans ** 3 == abs(n):
        break
if ans ** 3 != abs(n):
    print (n, 'is not a perfect cube!')
else:
    if n < 0:
        ans = -ans
    print('Cube root of ' + str(n) + ' is ' + str(ans))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is:

```
found = false
for guess in range(0,n+1):
    if guess**3 == n:
        print("The cube root of ", n, " is ", guess)
        found = true
        break
if not found:
    print("The number ", n, " is not a perfect cube.")
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop increments the value, in this case guess. The guess = guess + 1 will mess things up.

code:

```py
n = int(input('n = '))
for guess in range(0, n+1):
    if guess**3 == n:
        print(guess, 'is the cube root of', n)
    if guess**3 != n:
        print("not a perfect cube")
```

You can also change the second if condition to elif, so that it will only run when the first condition is not satistfied.

```py
n = int(input('n = '))
for guess in range(0, n+1):
    if guess**3 == n:
        print(guess, 'is the cube root of', n)
    elif guess**3 != n:
        print("not a perfect cube")
```

Last, you can store it in a list, [number_found, isFound], like bellow.

Code:

```py
n = int(input('n = '))
found = [None, False]
for guess in range(0, n+1):
    if guess**3 == n:
        found = [guess, True]

if found[1]:
    print(found[0], 'is the cube root of', n)
else:
    print("not a perfect cube")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your 1st and 3rd if the statement is the same
Try this

```
n = int(input('n = '))
j = 0
for guess in range(0, n + 1):
if guess**3 == n:
    j = guess
else:
    guess += 1

if j == 0:
    print("not a perfect cube")
else:
    print(j, 'is the cube root of', n)
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't put guess = guess+1 in the first if in a for loop.